# Import from CSV, record already exist else successful, else failed

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I have a script that imports records to multiple database tables, all relation to one parent entity (address).

If the address already exist, extra columns should just be updated according to the csv. The same counts for all other entities. A counter (`$exist++`) should increase or an array (`$existingRecords`) should be filled with already existing records.

If mandatory fields are empty in the record, that record should be added to another array (`$failedRecords`) or another counter (`$failed++`) should increase.

If the address doesn't yet exist and should be created with all fields just a counter (`$successful++`) should increase.

In the end I have an array `$result` that give the number of failed, successful, and already existing (but updated) records, for user feedback.

How can I implement this in a nice clean manner without messing my current script too much up? Because what is happening right now, if a record already exist the `$exist` counter increase but the `$successful` counter as well, and I only want the `$exist` counter to increase if a record already already exists, and only the `$successful` counter should increase if a record still has to be added and was added successfully. Same goes for the `$failed` counter.

Here is my script (with what I tried):

```
public function import(CsvFile $csv) {
    $root = __DIR__.'/../../../../../';
    $file = $root.'var/data/'.$csv->getCsvName();
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");

    $batchSize = 25;
    $header = null;
    $successful = 0;
    $failed = 0;
    $exist = 0;
    $results = [];

    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, null, ";")) {
        if ($header === null) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }

        $record = array_combine($header, $row);

        // cast all values to correct data types
        foreach ($record as $key => &$value) {
            if (strpos($key, 'datum') !== false ||
                strpos($key, 'tijdstip') !== false &&
                strlen($value) == 8 &&
                is_numeric($value)
            ) {
                $value = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value);
            }

            if ($value === "") {
                $value = null;
            }

            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                intval($value) == $value ? $value = (int)$value : $value = (float)$value;
            }
        }

        // required fields
        if (!$record['name'] ||
            !$record['surname'] ||
            !$record['email'] ||
            !$record['phone'] ||
            !$record['street'] ||
            !$record['houseNo'] ||
            !$record['town'] ||
            !$record['postcode'] ||
            !$record['location'] ||
            !$record['lecture'] ||
            !$record['session'] ||
        ) {
            $failed++;
            continue;
        }

        $student = $this->em->getRepository(Student::class)->findStudent(
            $record['name'], $record['surname'],
            $record['email'], $record['phone']
        );

        if (!$student) {
            $student = new Student();
            $student->setName($record['name']);
            $student->setSurname($record['surname']);
            $student->setEmail($record['email']);
            $student->setPhone($record['phone']);
        } else {
            $exist++;
        }
        $student->setAge($record['age']);
        $student->setLength($record['length']);

        $address = $this->em->getRepository(Address::class)->findOneBy([
            'street' => $record['street'],
            'houseNo' => $record['houseNo'],
            'town' => $record['town'], 
            'postcode' => $record['postcode'],
        );

        if (!$address) {
            $address = new Address();
            $address->setStreet($record['street']);
            $address->setHouseNo($record['houseNo']);
            $address->setPostcode($record['postcode']);
            $address->setTown($record['town']);
        }
        $student->setAddress($address);

        $lecture = $this->em->getRepository(Lecture::class)->findOneBy([
            'location' => $record['location'],
            'lecture' => $record['lecture'],
            'session' => $record['session'],
        ]);

        if (!$lecture) {
            $lecture = new Lecture();
            $lecture->setLocation($record['location']);
            $lecture->setLecture($record['lecture']);
            $lecture->setSession($record['session']);
        }
        $lecture->setTime($record['time']);
        $lecture->setSubject($record['subject']);
        $student->setLecture($lecture);

        $validationErrors = $this->validator->validate($student);
        if (!count($validationErrors)) {
            $this->em->persist($student);
            $successful++;
        }

        if (($successful % $batchSize) == 0) {
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $csv->setImported(true);

    $this->em->persist($csv);
    $this->em->flush(); // Also persist objects that did not make up an entire batch

    $results['successful'] = $successful;
    $results['failed'] = $failed;
    $results['exist'] = $exist;

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the existing records counter with a flag that is set to TRUE only if the current record is an existing one, and use it at the end before persisting the record.
You can set the flag to FALSE on the beginning of each loop:

```
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, null, ";")) {
      $existingRecordFlag = FALSE;   // initialize the flag for the current record
```

then update it instead of the counter :

```
    if (!$student) {
        $student = new Student();
        $student->setName($record['name']);
        $student->setSurname($record['surname']);
        $student->setEmail($record['email']);
        $student->setPhone($record['phone']);
    } else {
        $existingRecordFlag = TRUE;   //update the flag
    }
```

then before persisting user check the value for the flag and according to it update the counter:

```
$validationErrors = $this->validator->validate($student);
if (!count($validationErrors)) {
    $this->em->persist($student);
    if ( !$existingRecordFlag){
         $successful++;           //new record 
    }else{
         $exist++;                //existing user
    }

}else{
      $failed++;                 //failed as the validations has errors
      continue;
}
```

also you can add the existing records to the batch counter as they might be updated, they can also be persisted with the successful ones

```
if ((($successful+$exist) % $batchSize) == 0) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your block handling the addresses you could an existing/failed counter quite easily:

```
$exist++;
if (!$address) {
    $exist--;
    $successful++;

    //...
}
```

This will always increase the exist-counter, but jump back if address is empty and increase the new address-counter instead. Alternatively you could work with `array_push($record)` and `array_pop($record)` to add/remove the current record from a list. This might cause memory issues, since you keep your records in multiple arrays and you might run into out of memory errors.

For missing mandatory fields you'd have to do a check on the $address afterwards to see if it's not empty/containing invalid data and then increase the counter/update the field.
If you want